# Log Viewers for Database-based Logs

Tags: sql-server, logging

I'm writing a distributed system which logs directly to database (actual log files are only used when there's no database connection). There are plenty of tools for parsing traditional log files but are there any general tools for parsing log data from the database? I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format are you logging in? It doesn't matter if you log to a database table or a text file, the parser still needs to understand the message format and - as far as I know - there is no well-known standard for storing log messages in a database table.

For example, will you store the message as one string in a (N)VARCHAR column, or will you store individual values such as EventDate, EventMessage, EventSource etc. in different columns with different data types?

Perhaps you're asking if there are tools to visualize and analyze logged data stored in a database table, in which case you should look for generic reporting tools.